# Fonts on Pygame not working, I keep receiving a NotImplementedError on the PyCharm software

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, pycharm

I'm new to pygame (I'm a C sharp girly) and am currently following a tutorial on how to get started and am getting pretty frustrated with this pygame font situation, it keeps printing a NotImplementedError(missing_msg) error every time I try to run my code, no idea what im doing wrong! Heres my code:

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()  # really important, cant run pygame without it!
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption('Runner')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
test_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)


sky_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/sky.png')
ground_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/ground.png')
text_surface = test_font.render('MyGame', False, 'Green' )

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.blit(sky_surface, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(ground_surface, (0, 200))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (300, 40))

    # draw all our elements and update everything
    pygame.display.update()  # updates the display surface
    clock.tick(60) # should not run faster then 60fps- set a max frame rate
```

Trying to display MyGame on the screen, but there is an error on the line where I instantiate `test_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)`

Error message:

```
: RuntimeWarning: use font: dlopen(/Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/font.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found
(ImportError: dlopen(/Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/font.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found)
  test_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    test_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(missing_msg)
NotImplementedError: font module not available (ImportError: dlopen(/Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/font.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hanamahmoud/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the following pygame issue: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/3596

Funny enough, I’ve only heard of 4 people having this issue, and you’re the second today. (The other person was on the pygame discord so you didn’t miss a question here on Stackoverflow)

You can either upgrade your OS to MacOS 12+, downgrade your Python to 3.10 so you can use pygame 2.1.2, or build pygame from source locally.

I recommend building from source locally, it’s pretty straightforward on Mac. Guide: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile